# Node.JS Module/Object that spans several files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on supporting a REST API that literally has thousands of functions/objects/stats/etc., and placing all those calls into one file does not strike me as very maintainable.  What I want to do is have a 'base' file that has the main constructor function, a few utility and very common functions, and then files for each section of API calls.

The Problem:  How do you attach functions from other files to the 'base' Object so that referencing the main object allows for access from the subsections you have added to your program??

Let me try and illustrate what I am looking to do:

1) 'base' file has the main constructor:

```
var IPAddr = "";
var Token = "";
exports.Main = function(opts) {
  IPAddr = opts.IPAddr;
  Token = opts.Token;
}
```

2) 'file1' has some subfunctions that I want to define:

```
Main.prototype.Function1 = function(callback) {
   // stuff done here
   callback(error, data);
}

Main.prototype.Function2 = function(callback) {
   // stuff done here
   callback(error,data);
}
```

3) Program file brings it all together:

```
var Main = require('main.js');
var Main?!? = require('file1.js');

Main.Function1(function(err,out) {
  if(err) {
    // error stuff here
  }
  // main stuff here
}
```

Is there a way to combine an Object from multiple code files??  A 120,000 line Node.JS file just doesn't seem to be the way to go to me....not to mention it takes too long to load!  Thanks :)

SOLUTION:  For those who may stumble upon this in the future... I took the source code for `Object.assign` and back ported it to my v0.12 version of Node and got it working.

I used the code from here:  https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign/blob/master/index.js and put it in a separate file that I just `require('./object-assign.js')` without assigning it to a var.  Then my code looks something like this:

```
require('./object-assign.js');
var Main = require('./Main.js');
Object.assign(Main.prototype, require('./file1.js'));
Object.assign(Main.prototype, require('./file2.js'));
```

And all my functions from the two files show up under the `Main()` Object...too cool :)

Comment: *not to mention it takes too long to load* and you think multiple files are faster??

Comment: @Jonas It can be, if there is a lot of functionality and most users use only a small proportion of it. On the other hand it can be slower because there are more disk operations. But you can get round that with webpack/minify/whatever.

Comment: While it's easy to share an object, you absolutely should not do this. An object with so many properties that you need multiple files to define them is just the wrong approach. Use composition!

Comment: @Bergi  Do you have any links I can reference that explains 'composition'?

Comment: @Jonas   If I only need one or two sections of API calls verses one file with all 3,000+ API calls, then yes, its much quicker to load.

Comment: @jd allen then simply delete the rest 3000 ??

Comment: @JDAllen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first each file works in its own scope, so all local variables are not shared.

---

However, as ***hacky*** approach, you may just add `Main` into global scope available everywhere by writing `global.Main = Main` right after you define it, please make sure that you require main file first in list of requires.

---

The ***better***(who said?) approach is to extend prototype of Main later, but in this case you may need to ***update a lot of code***. Just [mix-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) additional functionality into base class

file1.js

```
module.exports = {
    x: function() {/*****/}
}
```

index.js

```
var Main = require('main.js');
Object.assign(Main.prototype, require('file1.js'));
```

Comment: So `Object.assign(Main.prototype, require ('file1.js'));` gives me a:  `TypeError:  undefined is not a function`, and its pointing to 'assign'  :(   I should note that I am stuck using Node v0.12.  Do I add in Main to each subfunction file??

Comment: Hm... you need to upgrade NodeJS if possible, there a lot of cool features, for example `Object.assign` :-) 

If you don't want/can upgrade NodeJS - use either [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill), either rewrite code by something which will copy properties from required object into `Main.prototype`

Comment: > Do I add in Main to each subfunction file??
No, in this case each file is separate, until you will build final version of Main class

Comment: Could `_.extend` be a possible solution??

Comment: Yes, it is doing the same thing as `Object.assign`

Comment: Well, I just back ported the Object.assign code into my v0.12 and got it working.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Shure.
*constructor.js*

```
module.exports = function(){
 //whatever
};
```

*prototype.js*

```
module.exports = {
  someMethod(){ return "test";}
};
```

*main.js*

```
const Main = require("./constructor.js");
Object.assign( Main.prototype, require("./prototype.js"));
```